# Android Studio problems with Myapp Has stopped working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So, I decided to create an application with sqlite database. Then put an add button but when click on it, I have a message("The app has stopped working"). Below I gonna give logcat details:03-04 11:35:09.210 17673-17673/com.a00003454.tyreshopapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

> Process: com.a00003454.tyreshopapp, PID: 17673
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.a00003454.tyreshopapp/com.a00003454.tyreshopapp.AllTyresActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Tyre.table(ID INTEGER
>   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TyreBrand TEXT Size INTEGER Cost INTEGER );
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Tyre.table(ID
>   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TyreBrand TEXT Size INTEGER Cost
>   INTEGER );
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.a00003454.tyreshopapp.TyreDatabaseHelper.onCreate(TyreDatabaseHelper.java:33)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.a00003454.tyreshopapp.TyreDatabaseHelper.select(TyreDatabaseHelper.java:59)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.a00003454.tyreshopapp.AllTyresActivity.onCreate(AllTyresActivity.java:28)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)  03-04
>   11:35:12.643 17673-17673/com.a00003454.tyreshopapp I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 17673 SIG: 9

Comment: You should send the code

Comment: post your activity code and XML code.

Comment: Remove `.table` from `CREATE TABLE Tyre.table`.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query for creating table is incorrect

Instead of

`CREATE TABLE Tyre.table(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TyreBrand TEXT Size INTEGER Cost INTEGER );`

You should write

```
CREATE TABLE Tyre (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TyreBrand TEXT Size INTEGER Cost INTEGER )
```